# Not able to call OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm new with the unity and just wanted to check the OnTriggerEnter function if it is working or not. 
 So I just added this code to check, but there is no output in my console.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("hit: " + other.transform.name);
}
```

And I enabled isTrigger for all the gameObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both GameObjects must contain a Collider component. One must have Collider.isTrigger enabled, and contain a Rigidbody. If both GameObjects have Collider.isTrigger enabled, no collision happens. The same applies when both GameObjects do not have a Rigidbody component.

From the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: thanks for this wonderful suggestion, I totally forgot about making a rigid body.